# Google Search using python

Tags: python, django, google-api

I get data from input. When I click to `search button` I need to open webbrowser page and see my input data in google. How can I do that? Many thanks.

This is my code:

`views.py:`

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request, 'index.html', context={})

    # Handles the search once the submit button in the form is pressed
    # which sends a "POST" request
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Get the input data from the POST request
        search_query = request.POST.get('search', None)

        # Validate input data
        if search_query and search_query != "":
            return HttpResponse(search_query)
            try: 
                from googlesearch import search 
            except ImportError:  
                print("No module named 'google' found")

            for j in search(search_query, tld="co.in", num=10, stop=1, pause=2): 
                print(j)
        else:
            return HttpResponse('Invalid input.')
```

`index.html:`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="some text"><br>
        <button class="button" name="submit" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

`urls.py`

```
from django.urls import path
from firstapp import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='home')
]
```

All files are in `hello` folder. My app namely `firstapp` `path:` `C:\Users\user\Desktop\hello\firstapp`

`index.html` path is:

`C:\Users\user\Desktop\hello\firstapp\templates`

Comment: @barny, I do not want to ready code. I just would like to know where is my mistake:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to redirect to google you need to have your search textfield to use a parameter called `q`. Here is an `index.html` file that would work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <form action="https://google.com" method="GET">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="text" name="q" placeholder="some text"><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```